what is "carry in" in full adder?
I really don't understand where the carry in signal comes from. I've seen many answers saying it comes from the previous addition, so does this mean that the signals from A and B have been processed by other adders to accumulate all the information needed for a carry? From the table below, I really can't see the relationship between the carry in signal and the corresponding A and B inputs. Can someone explain this to me?
A   B   Cin     Cout    Sum
0   0   0       0       0
1   0   0       0       1
0   1   0       0       1
1   1   0       1       0
0   0   1       0       1
1   0   1       1       0
0   1   1       1       0
1   1   1       1       1


Try just adding two binary numbers by hand on a piece of paper. Line up each binary digit, appropriately. Then consider drawing a thin vertical line between each binary digit and thinking about that column as an adder. If you do that, then you will see where the carry-in comes from, I think.

@periblepsis I the concept of carry, my confusion lies in the fact that the carry in data is placed along with A and B into the adder. This means the carry in data should be obtained beforehand. So, is the carry in data calculated from other adders by first determining the carry from A and B, and then using that carry as the carry in for the current adder?

Yes, the simplest system (the one that works like doing it by hand) is called ripple carry. The carry-out of the earlier bit stage is fed into the carry-in of the next stage. So the lower-order bits are added first and the carry "ripples forward" through the system. The highest order bit's summation must wait for all that ripple-carry stuff to complete in the earlier stages. And that does take extra time. There are also fast carry-lookahead circuits, too. But that's not what you are asking about.

In case the confusion is about where the first carry in (for the LSB) comes from: it is hardwired to "0".

@Unimportant Or, for subtraction when using adders, a '1' while also inverting one of the operands like this. But good addition because that might have been a question on their mind.

@periblepsis I think I might have mixed up some concepts before. A full adder is designed to calculate the addition of one bit of two binary numbers, right? one of  1+1 + cin ;0+1+cin; 1+0+cin; 0+0+cin right? I thought full adder was designed to calculate multiple bit at once which is something like 10101 + 10001

@xinking A half-adder adds two binary inputs and produces a sum and a carry. A full-adder accepts two binary inputs and also a carry from the prior stage and generates a sum and a carry from that. So a half-adder has 2 inputs and 2 outputs. A full-adder has 3 inputs and 2 outputs. (when talking about one bit adders) A full adder can add 1+1+1 to get 1 as the sum and 1 as the carry. But a half adder can only add 1+1 to get 0 as the sum and 1 as the carry.

@periblepsis I totally understand, thank you !

@xinking I'm glad to hear it! Sounds like you may be getting it, now. And that's a very good thing. Best wishes then!

Look up the data sheet for a 54ls283 (or something similar).

It would typically come from another adder used to add another set of bits.
For instance say you wanted to add two 8 bit numbers, you would use 8 full adders, one for each bit position, with the carry out of each bit feeding the carry in of the next higher bit.
You could also use one adder and some shift registers to add any number of bits, with the carry out from each add shifted into the carry input for the next add.

If you want your adder to also be a subtractor you might also use the CIN of the lsb (in addition to inverting the subtahend) when subtracting.
